# How to change font size in .settitle in row builder (android auto)

Tags: fonts, row, size, android-auto, settitle

I need some help with Android Auto code on a simple question regarding font size. I can make font size changes in most Android/Java code for smartphone apps. However, for Android Auto there are some classes and commands that I couldn't find anything to change the font of a text, like a .setTitle inside a row builder (below the example in the Android code).

I really need to reduce the font in this example below (where "application" and "make the action" appear). I even looked for how to create a "Layout" file to direct to these .setTitle, but I couldn't find any instructions or help.

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Template onGetTemplate() {

    return new ListTemplate.Builder()
            .setTitle("APPLICATION")
            .addSectionedList(SectionedItemList.create(new ItemList.Builder()
                            .addItem(new Row.Builder()
                                    .setTitle("MAKE THE ACTION").setOnClickListener(() -> {
                                        startListening(specificIntent);
                                    })
```

I've tried to find a solution on several Android/Java code sites, in the official documentation for both Android and Android Auto, and I haven't been able to find any information to help.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to change the font size for apps built using the Car App Library. You could make a feature request [here](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/new?component=460472&template=1554359&pli=1) describing your use case.